# Why is calling an API from Vuejs showing an error in data even though its tested in postman?

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm trying to call an API in Vuejs project:

First i tested the API using Postman, in order for me to get the FormID i need to login first:

[image]

after that i will get the value of FormID so i can use it in other requests:

here i'm searching for an item using the above FormID and the status is success:
[image]

and so far all good.

what i'm trying to do now is implementing this API to Vuejs project as follow

first i'm calling login API:

```
async getUser() {
  let payload = {
    databasename: 'hidden',
    username: 'hidden',
    password: 'hidden'
  }
  const response = await this.$axios.post(
    '{{login URL}}',
    payload
  )
  console.log('Returning from getUser: ', response.data.results.FormID)
  return response.data.results.FormID
},
```

then the api to get the item:

```
async getItems(formId) {
  let payload = {
    FormID: formId,
    ..
  }
  console.log('getItems: ', payload.FormID)
  const response = await this.$axios.post(
    '{{item URL}}',
    payload
  )
  this.items = response.data.results
},
```

and this function to call these two function at the same time to ensure that the FormID isn't being regenerated from login request:

```
async fetchData() {
  try {
    const formId = await this.getUser()
    console.log('Received formId in fetchData: ', formId)
    await this.getItems(formId)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Fetching data failed:', error)
  }
},
```

here are the results from the implementation above:

[image]

the console log is showing the exact FormID yet i'm getting this:

[image]

I also tried to save FormID to local storage once the user login and call it from local storage to the request but faced the same issue.

any idea or suggestion? am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: Are you missing any cookies or other headers? Your Postman screenshots show 9 which is quite high